# Diode forward voltage

Tags: diodes

Where does forward voltage of diode come from? I thought that forward voltage came from the transistor Vbe voltage (as far as I know, a diode is made of a transistor) :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKljdM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This was explaining why the voltage is (most of the time 0,7V). But, I realize that voltage can be even greater. (1,3V for a [RS1BL diode](https://fr.farnell.com/taiwan-semiconductor/rs1bl/diode-fast-sgp-0-8a-100v/dp/1559133RL) that I plan to use).

Comment: A diode is not "just a transistor". A diode has one P-N junction. A transistor has two, either NPN or PNP. A transistor can amplify. A diode cannot. Where did you get the idea that a diode is just a transistor?

Comment: It's not just a transistor, I didn't explain myself clear. As far as I thought, a diode is made of a transistor.

Comment: @M.Ferru I’d rather say that a transistor’s \$V_{\rm BE}\$ voltage is generally around 0.7V because the B-E junction is a diode. But a diode is definitely not made of a transistor with a shorted B-C junction.

Comment: @user2233709 Ok, it seems that my memory is corrupted :/ 
Anyway, what make the forward voltage change? Used technologie ?

Comment: A diode is NOT made of a transistor. A diode works because of the PN junction characteristics. A transistor (BJT) works because of of the NPN (or PNP) junction characteristics. Because a BJT contains a PN junction, there are diode-like characteristics (blocking, forward voltage)

Comment: `as far as I know, a diode is made of a transistor` This is generally true for integrated ICs. Because, in a wafer, making a diode from a transistor by shorting B and C is quite easy. Anyway, you can find a nice answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/286824/silicon-diode-threshold-voltage-0-7) to your question.

Comment: @M.Ferru Do you know that the diode or transistor forward voltage change with the current?

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thanks, I will take a look to that post

Comment: @G36 Yes I do, this voltage can be found in the datasheet curves.

Comment: @G36 You just made me realize that 1,3V is just the maximum voltage rating. For my application (low current around 30mA, V forward is 0,7V). Thanks

Comment: The ideal diode will follow the Shockley equation but real diodes "contains" the ohmic resistance also. And this is why at "higher" currents the real voltage drop across the diode is larger than the Shockley equation predicts due to the diode resistance.

Comment: @G36 So, does it means that a diode with a higher maximum forward voltage can "drive" more current or that the inner resistor is larger?

Comment: No wrong. Diode forward voltage is an unwanted parameter. The ideal diode will have Vf=0V.

Comment: @G36 yes of course but this resistor exist anyway, so it may be possible to deduce some information from the this maximum voltage rating. (Even though it is faster to open the datasheet and take a quick look)

Comment: Larger diodes( larger area) will have a smaller Vf for a given current (smaller bulk resistance).

Comment: @M.Ferru You have so many questions running at once. A diode almost always has a different saturation current (y-axis projected intercept, \$I_\text{sat}\$) and a different emission coefficient than a BJT. Whereas small signal BJTs will have similar emission coefficients (\$\eta\$), diodes (ranging from small signal, to power, to LED, to ?) will have very wide ranging emission coefficients and even different activation energies (\$E_g\$.) So diodes tend to be all over the place. (Not to mention that the BJT has a more complex structure, usually, and another wire-bonded lead.)

Comment: A transistor-connected diode is more ideal than typical diode (ideality factor in the Shockley equation of 1 rather than 1.5 to 2) but they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the forward voltage of a diode depends on:

- the diode’s technology (germanium diodes vs silicon diodes, PN junction diodes vs Shottky diodes),
- the diode’s geometry (the larger the junction is, the smaller the forward voltage, everything else being equal),
- the junction temperature,
- the forward current.

As for “your” RS1BL diode, you can find the \$I_F\$ vs \$V_F\$ characteristic in the datasheet. You’ll see that \$V_F\$ should be close to 0.7V for low forward current (around 50mA).

Answer (score 0):

This is approximately what you will measure across a small-signal silicon diode (note the 0.058 volts change, for each 10:1 current change)

Id    Vd

10mA 0.658

1mA         0.600

0.1mA       (0.600 - 1*0.058)

0.01mA      (0.600 - 2*0.058)

1uA         (0.600 - 3*0.058)

1nA         (0.600 - 6*0.058)

1pA         (0.600 - 9*0.058)

The 0.058 volts change per 10:1 current change, does depend on doping profiles at the PN junction; this value of 0.058 is appropriate for **abrupt** junctions.

Notice there is only one junction. This is not a transistor.

By the way, you can use these diodes to sense the temperature; the voltage will drop by 0.002 volts per degree Centigrade rise, thus a negative coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

A diode consist of a N-P junction. During fabrication, recombination of mobile charges take place in both the layers. The depleted charge space, after recombination, acts like a charged capacitor ( 0.7V in Si) which stops further recombination. In a forward biased diode, the applied potential should be more than this threshold voltage for current to start flowing.